# PGF Plots Ternary Diagram - Undefined control sequence

Tags: pgfplots, undefined, ternary-diagram

I am going through the PGFPLOTS manual and copied the first code example from Section 5.13 Ternary Diagrams which I have placed into a document on overleaf.com. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% PGF Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}
\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.81, 0.19, 0.00)
(0.76, 0.17, 0.07)
(0.66, 0.16, 0.16)
(0.76, 0.07, 0.17)
(0.81, 0.00, 0.19)
};
\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.85, 0.15, 0.00)
(0.82, 0.13, 0.05)
(0.73, 0.14, 0.13)
(0.82, 0.06, 0.13)
(0.84, 0.00, 0.16)
};
\legend{$10$\textdegree, $20$\textdegree}
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get two errors, which do not stop compilation of the document but are flagged up as Undefined control sequence at \end{ternaryaxis}. The logs output is as follows for each error:

```
\pgfplots@already@computed@legend@node ...tdegree 
};\\\pgfplots@show@small@l...
l.29 \end{ternaryaxis}
```

It is a manageable issue at this point but I'd like to know a solution if possible before I get too far into my dissertation and it potentially becomes a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Adding `\usepackage{textcomp}` to the preamble solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you that has worked perfectly. Why is \usepackage{textcomp} required?

Comment: Because it defines `\textdegree`. (Yes, it might be better if the manual mentioned that.)

Comment: Thank you marmot, I'd like to accept your answer but can't see how to do so.

Comment: Because it is a comment. ;-) You could try to persuade Sebastiano to rewrite his answer and then accept his.

Comment: @marmot LOL very much :-). I'm incorruttible.

Comment: @niko86 Thank you very much for your appreciation. Good LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with the replace `^{\circ}` instead of `\textdegree` which required a further package as mentioned, correctly, in the @marmot's comments. This is another option adding `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}` to define `\circ` symbol of degree.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% PGF Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}
\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.81, 0.19, 0.00)
(0.76, 0.17, 0.07)
(0.66, 0.16, 0.16)
(0.76, 0.07, 0.17)
(0.81, 0.00, 0.19)
};
\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.85, 0.15, 0.00)
(0.82, 0.13, 0.05)
(0.73, 0.14, 0.13)
(0.82, 0.06, 0.13)
(0.84, 0.00, 0.16)
};
\legend{$10^{\circ}$, $20^{\circ}$}
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, accepted this answer. As you mentioned marmot's answer fixes the \textdegree error which comes directly from the PGF Plot manual. Replacing as you indicated also fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't worry, I am an humble user and I am very happy when somebody fixes your issues. My good lucky.